# Django - Passing array parameter to a view

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary

Are you able to return an array through to a django webpage from the python Views.py file?  There may be a way, but I can't figure out how to do it.  Now, if I put the array into a dictionary, and return that, I can access the array, which is fine for what I need to do, but I would like to know if there is a way to just return the array and access it on the django template.  Thanks:

I can access the following on the template with catarray.0.name.

```
catarray = [{"name": "Henry", "type": "Tiger", "Awesomeness": "Very"}, {"name": "Bob", "type": "Siamese", "Awesomeness": "Cool"}]
returnobject={'catarray': catarray}
return render(request, "home.html", returnobject)
```

I cannot access the following and was wondering if it's even possible.

```
catarray = [{"name": "Henry", "type": "Tiger", "Awesomeness": "Very"}, {"name": "Bob", "type": "Siamese", "Awesomeness": "Cool"}]
return render(request, "home.html", catarray)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can only pass a "context dictionary" to a template.

Comment: Ok, thanks Selcuk.  I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this. The reason that you always pass a dict to render is that each item has a key, which is the name by which you access it in the template. If you passed a list, you wouldn't have a key; how would you reference any of the values?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I more so just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing anything.  I came to the right solution on my own, but I felt like I might be doing something wrong.  Thanks for confirming.